# Sign Failing_noop (Tag 17) message with Taquito

Tags: p2p

I want to sign a message of bytes and make sure the signature cannot be used for an attack. The P2P message format defines tag 17 as [Failing_noop](http://tezos.gitlab.io/shell/p2p_api.html#failing-noop-tag-17) ensuring that any operation fails using this signed message.
If I want to construct a Failing_noop message, how do I have to sign it e.g. using [Taquito message signing](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/signing/#generating-a-signature-with-the-inmemorysigner)? Is it my responsibility to construct the bytes as defined in the Tezos documentation with tag 17 and the protocol parses the 8 bit always recognizing this is a tag 17? FYI: The docs do not show the need of the block hash - no idea why...

Update:
I am having a backend application that validates a [JSON-LD ODRL](https://www.w3.org/TR/odrl-model/#aimsModel) file according to a specific schema and content. This JSON will be used inside a smart contract (SC) and I have to make sure that the file was not modified after the validation. Therefore I would like to sign it by a SK that is known by the SC (public key in a validator registry). I asked myself how I can make sure that this signed message cannot be used to trick the validator SK into executing an operation.

0x03 <- Magic byte (aka watermark)
8fcf233671b6a04fcf679d2a381c2544ea6c1ea29ba6157776ed8424c7ccd00b <- branch (genesis block)
11 <- noop (tag 17)
00000005 <- length
48656c6c6f <- Hello (in my example the JSON)

So, if I use this convention of the bytes to be signed I understood that those bytes cannot be used for something else as the protocol will always parse for the tag? This was in my opinion similar to the string message signing for the login into an application "Sign in with Tezos" where the user needs to sign a message to prove he owns the SK but the user wants to be sure that his signature is not abused? Or am I misunderstanding the concept completely?

Comment: Hi jdsika, I just want to ensure I understand correctly before answering. Are you trying to ensure that previous signatures cannot be used to sign other operations? Signatures are unique to the operations' forged bytes being signed. I am pretty certain that the Failing_noop is a response from the RPC of a failure of the process trying to be injected. So, I am unsure what you mean by constructing the failing_noop message. The values can be obtained from the contents. However, I will need to look into the type support for it

Comment: I edited my question above

Comment: The goal of the signature is to validate data using the SK rather than a PK. this way the data could not be signed by anyone that knows the PK. Since the pk is also obtainable by the PKH

Comment: Are you looking to sign the JSON using the application itself for validation? or by the user to sign the JSON to be seen as a valid user and the current user?

Comment: Please feel free to reach out to me on slack, discord or telegram! it may make back and forth a little faster :D

Comment: signed by SK obviously as P(rivate)  and P(ublic)  Key can be mixed up ;)

Comment: The user created the JSON and sends it to the application which validates it and signs it. The signed message can afterwards be used by the user to call the Smart Contract entry point to hand over the signed json. The smart contract can then validate with the public key if the signed json is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release v17.2.0 of Taquito added the ability to sign `failing_noop` messages

Comment: Thank you for the support!